# Setup nana with CMake in CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, c++14, nana

I been trying to setup Nana with CMake in CLion but i don't know how to setup the cmake to load Nana .

I make a try to use the Nana cmake that is given [here](https://github.com/cnjinhao/nana/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) but i cant find a way to make it function, or maybe i dont know how to use CMake with a library that don't have a CMake search function.

I'd try [this](https://github.com/cnjinhao/nana-demo/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) but i dont have the knowledge to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the latest versions of cmake and CLion and tested nana, and nana-demo. By the way I fixed some issues, but could not see any serios problems.

Until now, that I rechecked your question and see that you pointed to a very old and outdated: https://github.com/cnjinhao/nana-demo/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt and not to the "official" nana-demo: https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-demo/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt (we will update that old version too, just in case)

Please test with nana from latest hotfix branch:

https://github.com/cnjinhao/nana/tree/hotfix-1.7.1

and with the corrresponding nana-demo:

https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-demo/tree/hotfix

which are the latest actualizations. Here you have the find_library.